# Flutter : How to use connectivity_plus with go_router package

Tags: flutter, dart, connectivity, flutter-go-router

I am trying to add network connectivity validation to flutter application , I am using `go_router` for routing and navigation . I want to push user to other page if he is not connected to internet. I was trying to use `connectivity_plus` for checking network connection. can we use `streamBuilder` or any other thing to check connection continuously while using the application.

I tried building `Streambuilder` with navigation bar widget but is there any better way of doing this.
Following is code example of body part of navigation widget about how I built using streamBuilder:

```dart
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ConnectivityResult> snapshot) {
          print(snapshot.toString());
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            ConnectivityResult? result = snapshot.data;
            if (result == ConnectivityResult.mobile &&
                result == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
              return _pages[_currentIndex];
            } else {
              return NOTConnected();
            }
          } else {
            return NOTConnected();
          }
        },
      ),
```

This is not working as expected .
How can we use this in `go_router` routes ?

Comment: You can use the `onConnectivityChanged` stream to act like a listenable that is usually passed to the `refreshListenable` property of `GoRouter` by following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71532680/13625293)